# Cd url is going to 404

Tags: jss, experience-editor, sitecore-api, container, nextjs

I have downloaded Sitecore Next JS containers setup and installed XP1 in our local instance. But the default CD url is going to 404. The CM Sitecore url including Experience Editor & Preview  and the rendering host url is working correctly but the CD url is going to 404. Is this expected?

Referred the below link for local setup

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--setting-up-a-development-environment-with-the-sitecore-containers-template-for-next-js.html

Thanks,
Shakti

Answer (score 0):

Can you please double-check your CD site created from this template `sitecore/templates/Foundation/JSS Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Site` under `Site Grouping Item` at

```
/sitecore/content/jss-sxa/jss-sxa-site/JSS Settings/Site Grouping
```

in `JSS Setting`.

[image]

If only the CM site exists, create a new site with this template `sitecore/templates/Foundation/JSS Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Site`.

[image]